# Minicom Serial Port Connection Output

Tags: linux, serial

I have recently purchased a Cisco PIX 501 firewall and I have connected to the console port with a serial port USB adapter. After doing this I open up my terminal and start minicom. Here are my configurations for minicom:

[minicom-conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OfJ2.png)

After verifying the configurations I exit out of the configuration window and power on my firewall. After doing this I get this output in my terminal:

[Terminal Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YngpB.png)

I get this text continuously.

In addition to this, I have tried to connect to another Cisco device but I receive the same output

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your config looks ok. I use screen for this, never quite got minicom working fine. Supposing the usb adapter is

```
$ ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0
crw-rw----. 1 root dialout 188, 0 Apr 20 20:37 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

then:

```
screen /dev/tty 9600,-cstop,-cs8,-parenb
```

so 9600 baud, one stop bit, 8 data bits, no parity.

If your user is not member of the dialout group (or group indicated on the output of ls), run it as root.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I still cannot see text even when using screen. The cursor jumps around but thats all that happens.

Comment: have you tried with another switch/router? Just to make sure your usb adapter is ok?

Comment: Hello, I have tried another Cisco device and get the same results

Comment: ok, and does it by any chance work ok from a pc running Windows? I think nowadays people use putty because hyperterminal is no longer available (not sure, I just believe I overheard someone say it)